# Re-pairing a list with the dictionary it was pulled from

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

So i pulled all the keys from a dictionary and i sorted them in order by descending number. The values for these keys were all lists the same length long. My question is, once i pull these keys from the dictionary and put it in a sorted list. How can i than print the keys, with all their values based on the sorted list i just made

for example

```
D = {5:[item1,item2,item3],6:[value1,value2,value3],1:[part1,part2,part3]}
```

so i want the code to output once it's sorted such as

```
part1   1     part2    part3
item1   5     item2    item3
value1  6     value2   value3
```

But I don't understand how to print them in the order of the sorted list, while then printing their matching components with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> D = {5: ["item1", "item2", "item3"], 6: ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
... 1: ["part1", "part2", "part3"]}
>>>  sorted([
...      (v1, k, v2, v3) for (k, (v1, v2, v3)) in D.items()], 
...      key=lambda x: x[0])
[('item1', 5, 'item2', 'item3'), ('part1', 1, 'part2', 'part3'), ('value1', 6, 'value2', 'value3')]
```